# css button and link changing slowly when mouse hover

Tags: html, css

I'm with a huge project and I can't find what is making a slowly transition.

Basically I want exactly this as the following snippet.

but in the project this transitions is happening really slowly. Any ideas why? is there a css tag I'm missing?

```css
.checkout-options {
  margin: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
label.checkout-btn {
  padding: 20px;
}
label.checkout-btn a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #36526D;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
label.checkout-btn a:hover,
label.checkout-btn a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #195a96;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 23px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkout-options">
  <div class="checkout-options--noregister">
    <label class="checkout-btn"><a href="#!/shipping">Buy</a>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't see any defined transitions, are you missing something along the lines of `transition: all 0.2 ease-in-out` in `label.checkout-btn a`?

Comment: We need to see the non-working code, the working code does nothing for us.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith It's impossible to reproduce it , so I posted the expected event.

Comment: If you have chrome, right click,  on the button you have the trouble with click "inspect element", and at the bottom right, on tab "styles" look for a transition. If you find it, it should say on which sheet it is set, and on which line.

Comment: @Eduárdó thanks! that was the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to add : transition: 0s; to your css. To see if that makes a difference. See snippet.

```css
.checkout-options {
  margin: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
label.checkout-btn {
  padding: 20px;
}
label.checkout-btn a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #36526D;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
label.checkout-btn a:hover,
label.checkout-btn a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #195a96;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 23px;
  transition: 0s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkout-options">
  <div class="checkout-options--noregister">
    <label class="checkout-btn"><a href="#!/shipping">Buy</a>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```